# Alt+Shift combination isn't working on Lubuntu 14

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support, lxde

Well, I've just installed Lubuntu with two langauges and for some reason when I'm pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, things just don't work and the language isn't changing.
This is the first time that this some kind of problem happens for me.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks.

[image: Keyboard layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you see that tiny "US" down to the right? right click it, "keyboard layout handler" settings. In the new window that appears there's "Change Layout Option". Choose the button combination you want from there.

I tried playing with that window in the picture before but it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks, it did work but I had to uncheck "Keep system layout" before I could've click on the Change Layout Option

Comment: well looks like I unchecked it long ago that I forgot! XD ...I don't know what it does anyway

Comment: hahahahaha XD any time :D